# Failing to deserialise a text/html json response

Tags: javascript, java, c#, json

I am working on an integration into an old API which for some reason returns the json data as a text/html response. I have tried to Deserialse this string using Newtonsoft in C# and also using various javascript libraries including JSON.parse() but all have failed.

The actual response looks like a valid json object but it fails to get deserialised:

`{"err":201,"errMsg":"We cannot find your account.\uff01","data":[],"selfChanged":{}}`

I am taking it that there are some special characters or that the actual response is in a format that any of my parsers cannot not deserialise out the box. I have attached various code samples in various languages including curl. I would really appreciate if someone could help deserialise the response object in C# or point me in the right direction.

**C#**

```
var client = new RestClient("http://47.89.182.211:8080/index.php/account/login");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("appVersion", "0");
request.AddParameter("password", "xxxxxx");
request.AddParameter("platform", "5");
request.AddParameter("platformId", "xxx@xxx.com");
request.AddParameter("userType", "4");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

**Java**

```
Unirest.setTimeouts(0, 0);
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://47.89.182.211:8080/index.php/account/login")
  .header("Accept", "application/json")
  .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .field("appVersion", "0")
  .field("password", "xxxxxx")
  .field("platform", "5")
  .field("platformId", "xxx@xxx.com")
  .field("userType", "4")
  .asString();
```

**Javascript**

```
var data = "appVersion=0&password=xxxxxx&platform=5&platformId=xxx%40xxx.com&userType=4";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://47.89.182.211:8080/index.php/account/login");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.send(data);
```

**Curl**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://47.89.182.211:8080/index.php/account/login' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'appVersion=0' \
--data-urlencode 'password=xxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'platform=5' \
--data-urlencode 'platformId=xxx@xxx.com' \
--data-urlencode 'userType=4'
```

Please let me know if you are able to parse the response into a valid json object or deserialise it into a C# or Java object.

Comment: The very first character is the issue. It's a zero-width space: https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+FEFF If you remove the first character, you can parse the rest just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This c# code works for me. I can't explain the null character issue being experienced. I have to imagine the site you are using would be giving all of their users trouble if that were the case. Regardless, here's something to try:

```
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
Dictionary<string, string> body = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "appversion", "0" }, { "password", "xxxxx" }, { "platform", "5" }, { "platformId", "xxx.xxx.com" }, {"userType", "4"}};
HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://47.89.182.211:8080/index.php/account/login");
msg.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
FormUrlEncodedContent fuec = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);
msg.Content = fuec;
var result = await hc.SendAsync(msg);
string response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(response[0]);
Console.WriteLine(response);
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(response);
Console.WriteLine(obj["err"]);
```

Comment: Thanks this definitely works for C# That blank character in the beginning is a bit perplexing.

Comment: @pattywoddle that's great! Now I'm really curious what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in C# by customizing the JsonMediaTypeFormatter (from the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client) like so:

```cs
using var client = new HttpClient();
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "UrlToLoginPageHere");
using var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

var formatters = new[]
{
    new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes = { new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html") },
    },
};
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Rootobject>(formatters);
```

Where `Rootobject` is an object representing your JSON model (e.g. in Visual Studio, select Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes).

Comment: Does this fix the issue of the first character being a non-breaking zero width space?

Comment: @ChrisG where do you experience the zero width space? I ran the request in Postman and I do not get that character.

Comment: @Crowcoder I fetched the URL using node and logged `replyText.charCodeAt(0)`. It's invisible in Postman or the browser because it's a zero-width character: https://pastebin.com/5HwPYk9R

Comment: @ChrisG you are onto something. I just printed the characters in C# and there is definitely a character in the first position. I am going to try and remove this and see if this works.

Comment: @ChrisG I now implemented it with c# and JSON.NET has no problem deserializing the response as json. And character at [0] is "{"

Comment: @Crowcoder Feel free to run my node code, that's why I posted it. We also maybe shouldn't clutter up the comment space below an unrelated answer.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG your solution and sample code really helped. That blank character at the beginning is a definite issue.